# Хранение отзывов в базе данных

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как можно хранить в БД отзывы по объектам? Если все объекты разделены на таблицы - парки, кафе, театры и т.д. и по каждому объекту каждой группы надо хранить отзыв, комментарий. Не придумаю никак оптимальное решение.

Comment: Можно создать отдельную таблицу для отзывов (уникальный идентификатор объекта, идентификатор отзыва, содержание, дата)

Comment: @Qwerty67888, создаете таблицу групп, затем создаете таблицу объектов, затев таблицу отзывов, все это связывается по первичному ключу.

Comment: >просто предполагается, что объектов будет достаточно много, это нужно для карты Пензы

а разве в Пензе сотни миллионов или миллиарды кафе/ресторанов/театров? Полагаю, что нет. Поэтому вы можете запросто свести все объекты в одну таблицу (максимум их там будет несколько тысяч, а с учетом того, что это лишь дипломный проект, то, возможно, даже не тысяч, а сотен или десятков. Для любой СУБД - это пустяки)

Comment: что тогда будет являться первичным ключом в такой таблице?

Comment: >мне непонятно что будет в таблице отзывы - какие поля ?

создайте таблицу "Тип объекта" В нее занесете все возможные типы - ресторан, кафе, театр, парк и тд. Затем таблицу объектов. В ней данные по всем вашим театрам-паркам в с внешним ключом на таблицу типов. Затем таблицу отзывов, в которой будете хранить информацию об отзывах с внешним ключом на таблицу объектов. Вот и всё

Comment: добавление поля дата в такую таблицу тоже спорный вопрос - если по одному и тому же объекту будут одновременно пытаться записать новый отзыв - будет конфликт.

Comment: >если по одному и тому же объекту будут одновременно пытаться записать новый отзыв - будет конфликт

что за чушь? Вы сможете добавлять любое число записей по любому объекту - для этого у вас будет целая таблица

Comment: то есть в таблице отзывы примерно поля будут =  уник.id  отзыва, id  объекта( внешний ключ) , содержание отзыва?

Comment: да, именно так

Comment: спасибо, растолковали ))

Comment: не за что)

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть таблицы типа:

```
 Имя таблицы    Поля
 -------------------
Парки           id, name, ... 
Рестораны       id, name,  ... 
...             id, name, ...
```

Самый простой способ на мой взгляд создать таблицу "Отзывы" с полями id (ИД отзыва), table_name (имя таблицы, в которой храниться объект, к которому относится отзыв), obj_id (идентификатор объекта в таблице table_name, для которого и оставлен отзыв), comment (текст отзыва).

Чтобы выбрать все отзывы для Рестораны с id=23:

```
SELECT comment FROM Отзывы WHERE table_name = "Рестораны" AND obj_id = 23
```

Comment: Но лучше, конечно свести все в одну таблицу "Объекты" и добавить поле "Тип объекта", тогда в таблице Отзывы вам достаточно будет хранить ИД объекта и не надо никаких других полей для отнесения отзыва к тому или иному объекту